# 500 internal server error on laravel?

Tags: linux, laravel, centos

I made a project in laravel and when I migrated to a live server it gives me 500 internal error.

This is the first time I try to install laravel.

The problem occurs when I run `rm -rf public_html` AND `ln -s laravel/public/ public_html`

This is the error log:

```
[Sat Nov 08 12:57:46 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 08 12:58:01 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/%STACK%/public_html/index.php" is s$
[Sat Nov 08 12:58:01 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Sat Nov 08 12:58:01 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/%STACK%/public_html/index.php" is s$
[Sat Nov 08 12:58:01 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Sat Nov 08 13:03:27 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/%STACK%/public_html/index.php" is s$
[Sat Nov 08 13:03:27 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Sat Nov 08 13:03:27 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] File does not exist: /home/%STACK%/public_html/500.shtml
[Sat Nov 08 13:07:00 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/%STACK%/public_html/index.php" is s$
[Sat Nov 08 13:07:00 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Sat Nov 08 13:07:00 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] File does not exist: /home/%STACK%/public_html/500.shtml
[Sat Nov 08 13:09:02 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/%STACK%/public_html/index.php" is s$
[Sat Nov 08 13:09:02 2014] [error] [client IP ADDRESS ] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permissions of your app/storage folder to 755 if that doesn't works change it to 777. If you are running nginx on the server check /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and check the first which states the user running nginx and then

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /your/document/root/public_html/
```

change www-data by the user name you found in config file you can also validate it by running ps on terminal